# How do I execute code before a hashchange?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want to construct a `beforehashchange` event. I want to execute code *before* the `hashchange` event affects the page (i.e.: scrolls to the target).

The only things I know of that can change the hash (and cause a `hashchange` event) are:

- clicking `<a href="#foo">`, in which case I could capture the `click` event, and check for a link to a hash.
- changing the hash in the URL bar manually, which I can probably ignore (unless someone knows a way to detect this before it triggers the `hashchange`?)

Are there other ways to trigger a `hashchange`?

Comment: It could be changed by script `window.location.hash = "test"`

Comment: Is there any way to capture that as an event without changing my code everywhere I use `window.location.hash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only `hashchange` event. To capture some information before hash change, you can add a   attribute like `data-check-hash` to all link tags:

```html
<a href="#test" data-check-hash>foo</a>
```

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-check-hash]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $item = $(e.currentTarget), 
        hashValue = $item.attr('href').slice(1);

    // here goes your check code before hash change
    window.location.hash = hashValue;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing, because I wanted access to the scroll position before the `hashchange` event was fired.

One solution is to store the scroll position using the `scroll` event, and then respond to it on `hashchange`. For example, to reset the scroll position to what it was before clicking an anchor, you can do this:

```
var X = 0, Y = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    X = document.body.scrollTop;
    Y = document.body.scrollLeft;
});
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (e) {
    document.body.scrollTop = X;
    document.body.scrollLeft = Y;
});
```

Other than accessing the scroll position, I don't see any reason you would need a `beforehashchange` event.

Comment: Because you don't see any reason, doesn't mean other people don't see. I was looking for a `beforehashchange` event in order to cancel the event `hashchange` according to my app logic. For example, if a form is being filled and the user click in another link, I would like to ask the user to confirm if he wants to go away and navigate to that link and lose all information or not.