# How can i execute code before hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute code before the hashchange event affects the page. how can i execute before hash change event? I want to use a confirm box on before hash chnage so that if i press cancel button of confirm box it does not navigate to new hash. I do not want to change hash on cancel button because it opens the page as new again and my changes to page state are lost. Please provide me a quick solution.

Comment: please add some relevant code for which you have posted this question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673218/how-do-i-execute-code-before-a-hashchange

Comment: `$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    if(confirm("confirmation msg")){//call function} else{//do something else}
});`